# rake db:create throws “database does not exist” error with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using rails 5.2.2.1 with postgresql 10.6, and I'm not able to create a database in my development environment. When I run

```
bin/rake db:create
```

or

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "mplaces_dev" does not exist
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:696:in `rescue in connect'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:691:in `connect'
```

I am trying to create the database so, naturally, it does not exist. However rails should create it ... Here's my config/database.yml:

```
development:
 adapter: postgis
 database: mplaces_dev
 encoding: unicode
 username: postgres
 password: postgres
 host: localhost
 postgis_extension: true
 schema_search_path: "public,postgis"
```

However I also created all the extensions.
I've been at this for more than an hour, and still can't understand why this is happening ...

Thanks!

Comment: did you installed `postgres` in you're system? & `pg` gem in you're application

Comment: Yes, everything is installed.

Comment: did you tried the command by specifying the environment ?

Comment: Yes, by this command **bin/rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development**.

Comment: you're adapter name is incorrect `postgis` change this to `postgresql`

Comment: Sorry, but it is correct I am using **enable_extension "postgis"** extension here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192207/discussion-between-code-aks-and-uday).

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was because I had some Model dependant logic in one of my initializers.

This was never a problem before, but since setting up CI, I need to modify my project so that it excludes some logic from the initializers for the Model dependent part.

For initializer_example.rb:

```
# non model dependent
Aws.config(secret_key: xyz, access_key: zyx)

# model dependent
User.where(admin:true).update(field: value)
```

To:

```
# non model dependent
Aws.config(secret_key: xyz, access_key: zyx)

# model dependent
db_loaded = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection(&:active?) rescue false
if db_loaded
    User.where(admin:true).update(field: value)
end
```

This will run the initializer as usual ONLY if the database has been loaded (i.e in production)

As for my CI/Testing environments, I modify the RSPEC's to load the initializer again (bad practice I know) before testing (of course by this stage the environment should be configured so this time it will run as normal) using the code:

```
load "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/initializer_example.rb"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I googled for an hour before I found this solution. I also created a custom initializer to load some data. When I moved to a different machine, `rake db:create` failed. Commenting out the `Model.create` calls fixed this.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` works for me.